# Full width for Markdown table?

Tags: java, html, css, markdown

I am trying to set full width of a markdown table but as far as I see, it is not possible. I look at the documentation about that but there is not any property for table width:

https://arcticicestudio.github.io/styleguide-markdown/rules/tables.html

Here is my table:

```
| Class               | Method                                                                      | Rrequest          | Desc                                           |
|:--------------------|:----------------------------------------------------------------------------|:----------------------|:------------------------------------------------------|
| *AuthController*    | [**login**](http://localhost:8080/auth/login)                        | **POST** /auth/login  | Authenticates users              |
| *AuthController*    | [**signup**](http://localhost:8080/auth/signup)                      | **POST** /auth/signup | Registers users |
```

Comment: as far as I see, **it is not possible for markdown, right** ?

Comment: @schafer do you have an idea?